# How can I add the Black Gaps as shown in the Image in my ios project

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cashapelayer, caanimation

I have to add Black Marks(Gaps) on tap of a button on an animating circle as shown in the below pic [image]

I could able to draw the circle and animate it using the following code

```
self.circle = [CAShapeLayer layer];
self.circle.fillColor = nil;
self.circle.lineWidth = 12;
self.circle.strokeColor = [UIColor orrange].CGColor;
self.circle.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200);
self.circle.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:self.circle.bounds].CGPath;
[self.view.layer addSublayer:self.circle];

CABasicAnimation *drawAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
drawAnimation.duration            = 20.0;
drawAnimation.repeatCount         = 1.0;
drawAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
drawAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
drawAnimation.toValue   = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f];
drawAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];
[self.circle addAnimation:drawAnimation forKey:@"drawCircleAnimation"];
```

Now I should draw those marks on it while it is animating, EX: When I hit a gap button It should draw a black arc and then It should continue drawing the orrange Line,

So I need to know the position of the orrange layer's animation or the current stroke value to do this,, How to get the current stroke value ?

How could I do this, Any help would be appreciated

Comment: @ Lancelot de la Mare thanx for your reply,, Yea I agree but my question is how to get the position on the layer,, StrokeStart of the layer to draw?  gaps are not regular as in the pic,,It could be anywhere on the circle, while the orrange circle is animating, at the end point of the animating line it should add a Gap

Comment: @Lancelot de la Mare actually the big Gap in the  left top corner of my pic is not a gap, its the distance to be travelled by orrange layer,, Say I will add one more layer on the orrange layer and on tap of gap button I should change its color to gray ,,how do I do it?

Comment: While there may be a way to solve it using the route you picked, I would simply not use the `CABasicAnimation` since it interpolates the animation. I would use a `NSTimer` of sorts to redraw all layers under my control. There would be no need to query current keyframe since I would do the math myself.

Comment: It Would be greatull if you could post here some code samples